# C++ storing data from template function?

Tags: c++, templates, callback, unordered-map

I am trying to store data from a function argument into a unordered_map where that unordered_map is stored another unordered_map. In the second unordered_map the element is a struct. This is a simplified version of what it looks like:

```
//Callback.h

//Callback struct containing Object and Object function
struct CallbackStruct {
    EXClass* object;
    std::function<void()> function;
}

//Map with Keyboard keys as the key and CallbackStruct as the element
typedef std::unordered_map<Key, Callback> KeyCode;

//Map with an int as the key and KeyCode as the element
typedef std::unordered_map<int, KeyCode> BindingEvent;

class Callback {
public:
    //This function takes the data and stores it
    void bindKey(int Event, Key iKey, EXClass* classObj, std::function<void()> classFunction);
private:
    //This is where the data is stored
    BindingEvent handler;
}

//Callback.cpp

void Callback::bindKey(int Event, Key iKey, EXClass* classObj, std::function<void()> classFunction)
{
    //This is where the function data is stored
    CallbackStruct newCallback = { classObj, classFunction };
    handler[Event][iKey] = newCallback;
}
```

**Now this works very well but here is the problem**

This only works for the class EXClass. I need this to work for any class that has access to Callback.h

First, I placed the CallbackStruct in a template. After that I had to set all of the unordered_maps as templates. That means when I define `BindingEvent handler` it requires a template which means you can't define it in the class (maybe?).

I have tried setting the Callback class as a template but that wont work because it would only have the class of the class that initialized it. A single instance of Callback will be shared among multiple classes and the template needs to work with each one.

This is my source code with what I have tried:

```
//InputManager.h

template <class T>
struct Callback {
    T* Object;
    std::function<void()> Function;
};

template <class T>
struct KeyCodeStruct { //I have to place these in structs because templates are not allowed in typedefs
    typedef std::unordered_map<SDL_Keycode, Callback<T>> KeyCode;
};

template <class T>
struct BindingStruct{
    typedef std::unordered_map<int, KeyCodeStruct<T>> Binding;
};

class InputManager {
public:
    template <class T>
    void bindInput(SDL_EventType eventType, SDL_Keycode key, Callback<T> f);
    void updateInput(SDL_Event event);
private:
    template <class T>
    BindingStruct<T> bindingInput;      //This is where the main issue is; Can't do this
};
```

Comment: In `KeyCode`, the map is actually from `Key` to `CallbackStruct`?

Comment: In your "template" version, `Callback` is the template version of `CallbackStruct`, and `BindingStruct` is the template version of `Callback`?

Comment: @jxh Not sure I quite understand? If your asking why `KeyCodeStruct` and `BindingStruct` have templates they have to, to be able to use `Callback`, because `Callback` is a template. I think that's what you were asking?

Comment: Your classes in your pre-template version do not correspond 1-1 with the template version of them, and I wanted to clarify which non-template class the template class is supposed to correspond to.

Comment: @jxh Gotcha. I had to add the `KeyCodeStruct` and `BindingStruct` in the template version because I could not apply a template directly but you can apply the template if they are in a struct.

Comment: do you have some control for classes that uses `Callback` class?, could you add a common base class for all ?

Comment: @EmilCondrea I was thinking about that but if this will be a very large project and it seems wrong(?) to have do that for all the classes that use that. If there are no other options I may end up doing that.

Comment: I am wondering for what kind of actions do you use classObj and classFunc params? is classFunc a function pointer for class of which instance is classObj? will you call id using : `(*classObj.*classFunc)()` syntax ?

Comment: @EmilCondrea Yes, exactly! I am using this for an InputManager so that in my code, every class that has access to InputManager can "bind" a key to a function. This way I don't have to poll all the keys. The unordered_maps are there so that I can do a direct access check to see if say there is function bound to the key pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it! While I'm still not sure if it's possible to have a data structure in a template, I managed to get my Callback system to work. I just had to use the std::function and std::bind. For those who are interested in the end result here it is:

```
//InputManager.h

typedef std::function <void()> Callback;

typedef std::unordered_map<SDL_Keycode, Callback> KeyCode;

typedef std::unordered_map<int, KeyCode> Binding;


class InputManager {
public:
    template <class T>
    void bindInput(SDL_EventType eventType, SDL_Keycode key, T* newObj, void (T::*mf)())
    {
        inputBindings[eventType][key] = std::bind(mf, newObj);
    };
    void updateInput(SDL_Event event);
private:
    Binding inputBindings;
};

...

//InputManager.cpp

void InputManager::updateInput(SDL_Event event)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        if (inputBindings[event.type][event.key.keysym.sym])
            inputBindings[event.type][event.key.keysym.sym]();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is exactly what I was about to tell you, to use bind so you don't need anymore the object for storage, just a function pointer